# bool core data entry manipulation

Tags: core-data, boolean

I've done a lot of research and I read a lot about similar issues, but none of them are actually from type Bool like mine and I've been cracking on this issues for several days now.

Xcode 5
iOS application target:6.1 or 7.1 (on both the error stays) 
I have a coreData database and I just added a new entry of type bool.

When I try to set it to FALSE / TRUE I get the following errors:

```
1)
// in <Record.m> 
@dynamic poked;
// throws error: "Property implementation must have its declaration in interface
"Record""
The Entity in my CoreData DB is named Record and holds an Attribute named poked of type BOOL

2)
// in <Record.h>
@property (nonatomic, retain) BOOL *poked;
// throws error "Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type"
So now, I know it is because my DB entry is type bool, I can't use the retain attribute, but I've been breaking my head about it and can't find how to manipulate a BOOL DB entry on the web.

3)
// in iBAction for a button <mainViewController.m>
Record *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Record" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
newEntry.poked = TRUE;
// throws warning: "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') from 'int'"
```

Any ideas,?
Does somebody have an example of how to access a bool entry in a CoreData DB?

thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use core data, unless you are allowing use of primitive types, you are actually dealing with objects. So, your property "poked" is actually @property NSNumber *poked;.

You can assign values to it using @YES or @NO.

Comment: That helped already, thanks. But now, how do I use the DB entry in an if-statement, for example if I want to see if the value is "TRUE" or "FALSE", (or "YES"/"NO") ??

Comment: NSNumber has a method called "boolValue". So, you will read your value as if (object.poked.boolValue)